# Is there a way to compare with any pointer objects in golang?

Tags: go

I am trying to make a comparator, that takes either two string pointers, or two integer pointers and returns the result. any of pointer can be nil and i want true only when they have value and value is equal.

I tried with interface like

```
type T *interface{}
func compare(a T,b T) bool
```

because i had to check nil when cast *string to T, it is useless.

I am expecting to call function like

```
var a *string
var b *string
if compare(a, b){
  // do something
}
```

or

```
var a *string
var b *string
if a.equal(b){ 
  // do sth 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use type parameters to write the function:

```
func compare[T comparable](a *T, b *T) bool {
    return a != nil && b != nil && *a == *b
}
```

Here are some examples of calling the function:

```
a := "hello"
b := "world"
c := "hello"
var z *string
fmt.Println(compare(z, z))   // prints false
fmt.Println(compare(&a, z))  // prints false
fmt.Println(compare(z, &a))  // prints false
fmt.Println(compare(&a, &b)) // prints false
fmt.Println(compare(&a, &a)) // prints true
fmt.Println(compare(&a, &c)) // prints true
```

[Run it in the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/2W1HSfBadHi).

---

Here's how to write the function in Go version 1.17 and earlier:

Given that you are only working with two types, use [type assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to get the concrete pointer types and compare:

```
func compare(a interface{}, b interface{}) bool {
    switch a := a.(type) {
    case *string:
        b, _ := b.(*string)
        return a != nil && b != nil && *a == *b
    case *int:
        b, _ := b.(*int)
        return a != nil && b != nil && *a == *b
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Here are some examples of calling the function:

```
a := "hello"
b := "world"
c := "hello"
fmt.Println(compare(&a, nil))
fmt.Println(compare(nil, &a))
fmt.Println(compare(&a, &b))
fmt.Println(compare(&a, &a))
fmt.Println(compare(&a, &c))
```

[Run it in the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3pxjtAzIH9P)

Use the [reflect](https://godoc.org/reflect) API to compare all comparable types:

```
func compare(a interface{}, b interface{}) bool {
    if a == nil && b == nil {
        return true
    }
    if a == nil || b == nil {
        return false
    }
    va := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    vb := reflect.ValueOf(b)
    if va.Type() != vb.Type() {
        return false
    }
    if va.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        if va.IsNil() || vb.IsNil() {
            return false
        }
        va = va.Elem()
        vb = vb.Elem()
    }
    if !va.Type().Comparable() {
        return false
    }
    return va.Interface() == vb.Interface()
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! It works as I expected! :) One more thing. Is there a way to specify type? so both a and b must have same type? Instead of throwing an error?

Comment: Oops sorry I don't speak Go.. i mean instead of returning error
`compare() (bool, err) {
 if a.type() != b.type(){ return nil, error.New() }
}
`

Comment: I was hoping there is a way to restrict that A and B has a same type. It just returns false in case a and b has different type, but instead of that, i was hoping if a and b has different type, they can not even call the method.

Comment: The `compare` function can be simplified a little more: https://go.dev/play/p/l34I1weNSiY

Comment: @suz The updated answer requires the caller to use the same type for both arguments.